# Not able to install java 8 on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to install latest version of java 8 on ubuntu. I tried below

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

I got message

```
  Package default-jre is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b181-1~webupd8~2
  oracle-java8-installer 8u144-1~webupd8~0
  oracle-java6-installer 6u45-0~webupd8~8
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
```

Then I run command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

got error as

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily  Location:
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1515737732_ecd7adee8c373b9510eae0f55774956f
>   [following]   --2018-01-12 11:43:32-- 
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1515737732_ecd7adee8c373b9510eae0f55774956f
>     Connecting to download.oracle.com
>   (download.oracle.com)|202.88.188.203|:80... connected.    HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found  2018-01-12 11:43:33 ERROR
>   404: Not Found.
>
> download failed     Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.  dpkg: error
>   processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):   subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>     Errors were encountered while processing:    oracle-java8-installer
>     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: If I were you, I would ask this in Server Fault.

Comment: ok I added it on server fault    https://serverfault.com/questions/891867/not-able-to-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-15-04

Comment: I don't know the answer to this. But I think you are more likely to be helped there as they know more about this things

Comment: Well, you could try to perform `sudo apt-get update` to update your repos first of all. I always do it before any install. They might be outdated.

Comment: @jeprubio I tried it but same issue also when I run above command I get error for some packages as     W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

Comment: The reason you get 404s is because Ubuntu 15.04 has been end-of-life (unsupported) since January, 2016. Replace it with 16.04.

Comment: WHY DOWN VOTES. I have been provided system with ubuntu 15.04. I was looking for the solution if it can be done without updating OS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone facing same issue I solved it by following below link [Link](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: Installing OpenJDK instead of Oracle's isn't really a solution... There's a bug with Oracle JDK install scripts everywhere.

Comment: ok. I am not aware of this. thank you for information. But it can be used as quick fix for those who are running old OS. and system update in not possible and java installation is on priority :-)